# 403 Forbidden apache mac os

Tags: macos, apache, permissions, virtualhost

Help set up a virtual host. In the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I uncommented this line here:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Next, the file is opened, and in the end ordered a new virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/igor/sites/advanced"
    ServerName advanced
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/lab.domain-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/lab.domain-access_log" common

<Directory "/Users/igor/sites/advanced/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then added to the hosts 127.0.0.1 advanced. Restart Apache, but the browser displays a 403 error! What could it be?